# Permissible forms of out-of-class template member function definitions with trailing requires clauses

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following code, where a class `A` has a nested type `B` with template member functions containing trailing requires clauses naming the nested type `B`, and subsequently defined out-of-class:

```cpp
template <typename X, typename Y>
concept C = true;

struct A
{
    struct B {};

    template <typename T>
    void f1()
    requires C<T, A::B>;

    template <typename T>
    void f2()
    requires C<T, A::B>;

    template <typename T>
    void f3()
    requires C<T, B>;

    template <typename T>
    void f4()
    requires C<T, B>;
};

template <typename T>
inline void A::f1()
requires C<T, A::B> {}

template <typename T>
inline void A::f2()
requires C<T, B> {}

template <typename T>
inline void A::f3()
requires C<T, A::B> {}

template <typename T>
inline void A::f4()
requires C<T, B> {}

int main()
{
    A{}.f1<A::B>();
    A{}.f2<A::B>(); 
    A{}.f3<A::B>();
    A{}.f4<A::B>();
}
```

I've been unable to find/understand any definitive wording on whether:

- Trailing requires clauses can name nested types without explicit qualification in a similar manner to trailing return types
- Which of `f2`, `f3`, and `f4`, if any, should be accepted by a conforming implementation

The closest I could find in the draft standard is in [temp.mem],

> A member template of a class template that is defined outside of its class template definition shall be specified with a template-head equivalent to that of the class template followed by a template-head equivalent to that of the member template (13.7.6.1).

With 13.7.6.1 referencing [temp.over.link], in paragraph 7,

> Two function templates are equivalent if they are declared in the same scope, have the same name, have equivalent template-heads, and have return types, parameter lists, and trailing requires-clauses (if any) that are equivalent using the rules described above to compare expressions involving template parameters.

which as far the requires clause itself is concerned, equivalence seems to be specified by

> they both have requires-clauses and the corresponding constraint-expressions are equivalent.

In any other context, I would expect that all forms of the constraints in `f1` through `f4` are (formally) *equivalent*, but I'm not familiar enough with the standard to conclude this for myself.

In terms of implementations, clang and gcc appear to consistently accept all definitions, whereas MSVC differs, and has recently changed in behaviour:

| Function | [gcc 12.2](https://godbolt.org/z/rrnd6GhnT) | [clang 15.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/MqvM68ncn) | [MSVC 19.33](https://godbolt.org/z/5hK1nas3K) | [MSVC Latest (19.34?)](https://godbolt.org/z/35zErnjq9) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `f1` | Accepted | Accepted | Accepted | Accepted |
| `f2` | Accepted | Accepted | error C2244: 'A::f2': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration | error C2244: 'A::f2': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration |
| `f3` | Accepted | Accepted | error C2244: 'A::f3': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration | error C2244: 'A::f3': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration |
| `f4` | Accepted | Accepted | Accepted | error C2065: 'B': undeclared identifier |

Comment: One can use unqualified `B` in function arguments and in noexcept specifiers too (in templates and non-templates), I don't see why requires clauses should be any different. But I cannot find where the standard says so.

Comment: @n.m. I think that part should be handled by https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#1.sentence-2 which says everything after the _declarator-id_ is in scope of the class. But whether `C<T, A::B>` and `C<T, B>` are considered _equivalent_ seems less clear to me.

Comment: In what sense can they be non-equivalent?

Comment: @n.m. By the rules stated in [temp.over.link]. I tried to give an answer as best as I can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am referencing the current draft instead of the C++20 draft, because there was a major revision of the relevant sections which made them much clearer.

According to [[basic.scope.class]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#1.sentence-2) everything after the *declarator-id* of a (non-`friend`) redeclaration of a member function is in scope of the class and should therefore be able to lookup `B` with unqualified name. The trailing *requires-clause* appears after the *declarator-id* `A::fX`.

However I think that because the template parameter `T` is used in the *constraint-expression* [sentence 1 of [temp.over.link]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.over.link#5.sentence-1) applies which states that the expressions `C<T, A::B>` and `C<T, B>` are equivalent only if using them in two function definitions would satisfy ODR except that the template parameters may be renamed. However ODR doesn't allow using different token sequences to name `A::B`.

But since the two expressions are still *functionally equivalent* this would then make the cases in which they are mismatched *ill-formed; no diagnostic required* (IFNDR), meaning that `f2` and `f3` would be invalid, although that doesn't need to be diagnosed. This is because equivalence must be checked to determined whether the out-of-class definition is a redeclaration of the member already declared in the class. And if two constructs are functionally-equivalent but not equivalent when equivalence would affect semantics of the program, then the program is IFNDR.

I think the equivalence rules are quite difficult to follow at times, so I might not be correct on that. But it seems that MSVC is following a similar interpretation and I suspect that the `'B': undeclared identifier` error in the latest version is just a regression. The behavior of the other compilers is also compatible with this interpretation.